# openTok integration iOS - getting library missing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opentok, tokbox

I am adding `Tokbox` to my project for chat purpose.I downloaded sample textchat app from `opentok` site.And installed `opentok` framework using `cocoapods`. After integrating all those, I am opening my `xcworkspace`. Still am missing two library files (`opentokUI` and `OTKTextchatComponent`). Please help me solve this. Reference link [click here](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios)

Comment: Please add more information to your question so we can assist. What specific messages are you getting?